# Update WritableBitmap after Image.Source has been set

Tags: c#, wpf, writablebitmap

I am trying to use `WritableBitmap` to do some pixel level manipulation of bitmap images.But i can't get it working.What i want to do is manipulating pixel data of `WritableBitmap` after i assign `Image.Source` property with my bitmap.I googled and the only thing i found is call to `bitmap.Invalidate()` method but it seems to be deprecated as i couldn't find that method in `WritableBitmap` class.following is the code i am using to get the image updated but no luck:

```
    wbitmap.Lock();
    wbitmap.WritePixels(rect, pixels, stride, 0);
    wbitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    wbitmap.Unlock();

    //given that i've already assigned image.Source with "wbitmap"
    image.InvalidateVisual();
```

any thoughts on this?

**EDIT**

i would appreciate any suggestion for other way of **FAST** 2D drawing in WPF better that `WritableBitmap`.

Comment: Lock/AddDirtyRect/Unlock won't actually change any pixel data. Did you try WritePixels? Calling InvalidateVisual on an Image control should never be necessary.

Comment: sure i do , i updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following simple example shows how to continuously write a WriteableBitmap while it is assigned to the Source property of an image control.

The XAML is just this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="image"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code behind there is a timer that overwrites the WriteableBitmap ten times per second with a random pixel color value. Note that you have to allow unsafe code in the Visual Studio Project Properties (in the Build tab).

Alternatively to `Lock`/`AddDirtyRect`/`Unlock` you could also call `writePixels`. However, the `Lock` approach also allows that another, non-UI thread writes to the `BackBuffer`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly WriteableBitmap bitmap
        = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        image.Source = bitmap;

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1) };
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private unsafe void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pixelValue = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0xFFFFFF;

        bitmap.Lock();
        var backBuffer = bitmap.BackBuffer;

        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.PixelHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.PixelWidth; x++)
            {
                var bufPtr = backBuffer + bitmap.BackBufferStride * y + x * 4;
                *((int*)bufPtr) = pixelValue;
            }
        }

        bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight));
        bitmap.Unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer. another question , is there any faster way to do 2D graphics in WPF?

Comment: That depends on how exactly you define "2D graphics". You may want to take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i wanna design a paint like bitmap editor , which route shall i go with?

Comment: Bitmap editor sounds pretty much like you could well use WriteableBitmap.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

Comment: it is a good wrapper around WriteableBitmap but it drops performance.